# Cannot print the exception in plsql

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql

The code is running for existing values. But, if I enter a number out of table, `exception` part isn't working.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Please post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Also, please don't use ALL CAPS. ALL CAPS reads as shouting. You probably don't want to be shouting at the people you're asking to help you. :-)

Comment: By the way, I suggest using [indentation](https://codehs.gitbooks.io/introcs/content/Programming-with-Karel/how-to-indent-your-code.html) when writing code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with the `exception` part is that it'll never be executed. There's no `select` statement in your code which would raise it. You'll say that there is - in a cursor. Yes, you're right, but - if cursor doesn't fetch anything, it'll just silently exit the loop, close the cursor and end the procedure.

Therefore, you'll have to do something else to find out whether department you entered as as parameter exists or not. A simple option is to actually *count* number of rows fetched. Then, at the end, check its (counter's) value and display appropriate message.

- as I don't have your tables, I used Scott's sample `emp` table
- also, I used a cursor `FOR` loop which is way simpler to use as Oracle does most of the *dirty* job for you (you don't have to declare a cursor variable, open/close cursor, take care about exiting the loop)
- there's no processing in my code; you'd put your "grades" checking in there

So:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    l_cnt  number := 0;    -- count number of rows fetched by cursor
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select empno from emp
  5                  where deptno = &par_dept_code
  6                 )
  7    loop
  8      l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;
  9      -- do some processing here
 10    end loop;
 11
 12    if l_cnt = 0 then
 13       dbms_output.put_line('There''s no such deptno - insert a valid value');
 14    else
 15       dbms_output.put_line('display result here');
 16    end if;
 17  end;
 18  /
Enter value for par_dept_code: 20
display result here

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> /
Enter value for par_dept_code: 10
There's no such deptno - insert a valid value

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```